# Error while trying to use Tensorflow Object Detection API train.py file or model_main_tf2.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am having some issues as I am trying to use Tensorflow's Object Detection API for an object detection model I try to set up.
I keep having a Unicode error that seems to be similar whether I use the train.py or model_main_tf2.py files but can't seem to proprely locate that error.
Here is the code I used and the error. My system runs on Windows 10.
Thanks in advance for your answers and/or tips.

The command:

**!python train.py
--logtostderr
--train_dir=training/
--pipeline_config_path=training/EffDetD0.config**

The error:

````
2021-11-26 15:24:15.527841: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-11-26 15:24:19.597360: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-11-26 15:24:19.597749: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2021-11-26 15:24:19.598123: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2021-11-26 15:24:19.601296: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2021-11-26 15:24:19.601686: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2021-11-26 15:24:19.602067: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2021-11-26 15:24:19.602079: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-11-26 15:24:19.602460: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
WARNING:tensorflow:There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
W1126 15:24:19.602859  6764 cross_device_ops.py:1387] There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
I1126 15:24:19.607062  6764 mirrored_strategy.py:376] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 115, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\ishma\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\ishma\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 312, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\ishma\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 258, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 112, in main
    record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
  File "C:\Users\ishma\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 499, in train_loop
    pipeline_config_path, config_override=config_override)
  File "C:\Users\ishma\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py", line 138, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\ishma\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 118, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\ishma\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 81, in _preread_check
    compat.path_to_str(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 81: invalid start byte```
````

Comment: There may be something wrong with your config file.

Comment: Hi Aniket,
The only changes I made in the config file are the paths, for example:
`input_path: "ModelGarden/InputDataRing/TFRecordTrain/traintfrecord/train.tfrecord" `

Answer (score 1):

#### first answer

Try to add these lines to *model_main_tf2.py* to inspect the inputs are correctly inserted into the script.

```
...
## add the three prints to inspect the inputs fo the script
    with strategy.scope():
      print('', FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
      print('', FLAGS.model_dir)
      print('\n\n\n')
...
```

I had the same issue and after adding these lines to the code, I found out that the script was getting None for *pipeline.config* file. So after some investigation it was my fault giving having a misspelled word in the script command.

#### second answer

From what I can see in your error, maybe your file *pipeline.config* is not saved in utf-8 format. Try to change it into utf-8 format.